# return variable value from javascript function into html body

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A Simple Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script>
      var q = ["How many days are in an year?", "How many days does february have in a leap year?","How many hours equals to 1 day?"];
      var a = [365, 29, 24];
      var fd =["Incorrect! Its 365", "Incorrect! It has 29 days", "Incorrect! It has 24 hours"];

      function scores() {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = askquestion();
      }

      function askquestion() {
        var score=0;
          for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
            var question=prompt(q[i]);
            if (question==a[i]){
              alert("Correct Answer");
              score=score +1;
            }
            else {
              alert(fd[i]);
            }
          }
        return score
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> A Simple Quiz </h2>
    <hr>
    <script> scores()</script>
    <h2> The score is: </h2> <output id="finalscore"></output>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is my code. I'm trying to print the score next to "the score is: ". But I can't figure out a way! I know we can't use print statement or anything. But I was hoping there is a way out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to change this score time to time?? or it will be render only on page load.

Comment: there are only 3 questions that appear through dialogue box, so once the function's (for loop) is over the score is finalized. Hope I told you what you wanted to know.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hogfcjmc/ take a look. I have created a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also, on a sidenote you have mistakely closed the `<h1>` tag as `</h2>` :)

**Your JavaSript:**

```
var q = ["How many days are in an year?", "How many days does february have in a leap year?","How many hours equals to 1 day?"];
var a = [365, 29, 24];
var fd =["Incorrect! Its 365", "Incorrect! It has 29 days", "Incorrect! It has 24 hours"];



function askquestion() {
  var score=0;
  for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
     var question=prompt(q[i]);
       if (question==a[i]){
        alert("Correct Answer");
        score=score +1;

       }
      else{
        alert(fd[i]);
       }
  }
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Score is "+score; // On completion of the loop, you can append the result to your string this way.
}

askquestion();
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hogfcjmc/

**Edit:**

You have made 2 simple mistakes:-

**1**. When your `score()` method runs, the HTML still isn't present in the DOM. So any value set to innerHTML wouldn't work.

**Solution:**: Move your `<script>scores()</script>` after the HTML code like this.

```
.....
<h2> The score is: </h2> <output id="finalscore"></output>
<script> scores()</script>
....
```

**2**. Observe that you are using a wrong Id name `output`. It should be `finalscore`.

So your code will look like this:

```
document.getElementById('finalscore').innerHTML = askquestion();
```

Updated and working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xhs10xve/

Comment: You have made a trivial mistake...`document.getElementById('finalscore').innerHTML` it should be? and not `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML`

Comment: Also, when your script in the body runs, your HTML is not yet in the DOM..so the result isnt appended.

Comment: Hey! I knew how to get the score within the script itself. But I wanted it in the body tag. Could you please take a look at the area in the body tag where i provided space for the score? thats where i want the result to appear! thanks!

Comment: With those 2 changes, your code will work just fine. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

change the following line

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = askquestion();
```

to

```
document.getElementById('finalscore').innerHTML = askquestion();
```